# Robust regression does not converge after inclusion of interaction terms

Tags: r, linear-regression, robust

I am performing a linear regression to evaluate the effectiveness of mitigation measures, essentially reproducing the attached regression equation. However, I ran into problems of significant outliers and heteroskedasticity, which lead me to use a robust regression (I tried lmrob from robustbase and lm_robust from estimatr). Both functions work as long as I exclude the interaction terms (so for example only ß1 * X1 + ß2 * Z1) but as soon as I include the interaction terms (now ß1 * X1 + ß2 * Z1 + ß3 * X1 * Z1) I run into an error of the robustness algorithm not converging.
The interaction terms significantly improve my linear regression model results, so I would also like to include them in my robust model.
[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6cXS.png)

Comment: Make a reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @user2974951, how do I best do that without uploading my whole dataset?

Comment: If your dataset is too large upload a sample of it which still exhibits the same error. Paste the output of `dput` into your question, that is from the sample dataset.

Comment: @user2974951 if I sample the data to fit the character limit, i get an error message of: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: Can I upload my sample data somewhere so it's reproducable?